# regex for pattern in input type for version

Tags: html, input

What should be the `input type=""` for version ? Like for eg: `12.1.3.0`

I know we can use `pattern` then what should be the regex for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<input pattern="[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*" type="text">
```

As the version would keep increasing, we would not be know upto how many digits each field would go, So i would use  [0-9]* to match each field

Comment: But its also allowing just `10.1`.... Upto `10.1.0.0` should be mandatory while `10.1.0.0.X` optional

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" pattern="(\d+\.){3,}\d+" />
```

This pattern is valid for 4 subversions or more. Therefore `10.1.0.0.X` and more would be allowed, whereas `10.1.0` and less isn't valid.